# avoid zombie processes when using at

Tags: bash, at

I'm using [at](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/at.shtml) to schedule a script in a Centos based Docker container.

e.g. `echo "bash /path/to/script.sh" | at now + 1 minute`

It mostly works as expected with the exception being that it results in a zombie process every minute.
I'm guessing the behaviour is related to this line in the docs:

1. The at-job is executed in a separate invocation of the shell, running in a separate process group with no controlling terminal, except that the environment variables, current working directory, file creation mask (see umask(1)), and system resource limits .

I've seen and tried suggestions from [Remove a zombie process from the process table](https://serverfault.com/questions/575162/remove-a-zombie-process-from-the-process-table) to no avail.

Can I get the zombie ps to go away or is there an alternative way to do this that wouldn't end up with the same resulting zombie ps?

EDIT: contents of one of the scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1> >(logger -s -t $(basename $0)) 2>&1 
#probe the seed node if this isn't the seed node
# set -ex
[[ `hostname` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
ordinal=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
#if this is the first node then attempt to probe second until successful
if [[ $ordinal -eq 0 ]]; then
  while ! gluster peer probe {{gluster.service_name}}-1.{{gluster.service_name}}.default.svc.cluster.local; do sleep 2; done
fi
#if this is the second node then probe the first to create the trusted pool
if [[ $ordinal -eq 1 ]]; then
  while ! gluster peer probe {{gluster.service_name}}-0.{{gluster.service_name}}.default.svc.cluster.local; do sleep 2; done
fi
```

Comment: What is the content of your script?

Comment: Added. This goes into a Kubernetes ConfigMap and gets mounted in a container running glusterfs. The `{{...}}` are ansible vars that'll be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post back that I worked around this by just using cron.

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/1 * * * * /path/to/job -with args") | crontab -
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625233/400048

Note, if running in Docker you need to start crond.